# R: Take the names of the months in a TS Object

Tags: r, date

Imagine that you have the following time series. A monthly one

```
require(forecast)

a<-ts(seq(1:50),frequency = 12)

Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
3  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
4  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
5  49  50
```

I want to obtain the month for each of the data points. That would be a vector of length 50, that would have (Jan, Feb, ..., Mar)

```
> names(a)
 NULL
```

I tried also colnames. But no luck. Any suggestion?

Best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) month names** Try this:

```
> month.abb[cycle(a)]
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
[13] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
[25] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
[37] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
[49] "Jan" "Feb"
```

**2) yearmon** If what is really wanted is year and month then this gives a zoo `"yearmon"` class result:

```
library(zoo)
a <- ts(1:50, start = 2000, freq = 12)
as.yearmon(time(a))
```

**3) Date** or if we want `"Date"` class with the first of the month as the date:

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(time(a)))
```

or the last of the month:

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(time(a)), frac = 1)
```

**UPDATE**  Added (2) and (3).

Comment: What a crack! :). Then I use as.Date() to change the format. Thanks!

Comment: If that is what you want and not just the month then I have added a couple of more options.